# Getting pixel position of point in Matlab for MRI data

Tags: image, matlab, pixel

I can show the data from MRI in the figure. I used the source:

```
load mri
figure('Colormap',map)
load DCE_sec05_inp.mat
image(data2{1,1}) %i get 128*96 pixel picture
axis image
```

But I can´t find a solve how I can get the pixel position to workspace when I click to pixel in figure. I finded this code:

```
I = imread('cameraman.tif');  %read the image in I
imshow(I);                    %display I
[c,r,P] = impixel(I)
```

but I can´t get the mri data to imshow mode.
Thanks for whatever help

Comment: What happens when you use `imshow`? Do you get an error message? Or it just doesn't display anything? Also, you might want to use `imread` instead of `load` if you can.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't necessarily need `imshow`, try this:

```
image(data2{1,1}) %i get 128*96 pixel picture
axis image
[u v]=getpts;
```

The coordinates of the points you clicked will be stored in `u` and `v`.

Answer (score 0):

The image or the data you are reading is of type `map` (`mri`) which is not necessarily of the form `RGB` (`cameraman`). In order to show the image using `imshow`, you will require the map data as a second argument. For example, the first image in the mri data can be shown using the following syntax:

```
load mri
imshow(D(:,:,:,1), map)  %map is provided the mri.dat
```

Once you use `imshow`, you can use `impixel` like the example you provided.